# gradle - doLast closure not being executed when called from commandLine

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In my build.gradle i have the following lines of code:

```
    task aExecutionTask << {

    println 'hello says aExecutionTask, via the execution phase'

}



task aConfigurationTask{

    println 'hello says aConfigurationTask, via the configuration phase'
    doLast{
        println 'im last to get done'

    }

}
```

and when i run the aExecutionTask from the command line using

`./gradlew aExecutionTask`
 
the output is the following:

```
hello says aConfigurationTask, via the configuration phase
:app:aExecutionTask
hello says aExecutionTask, via the execution phase
```

Why did it not print out my doLast statement ? It clearly ran the task "aConfigurationTask" but it did not run its doLast. So then am i to understand that the aConfigurationTask was configured but not executed ? is that the concept ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is `evaluated` during the configuration phase.  So while the task is being configured the task was not actually executed.  `doLast` block will be called after a task is executed.  Using your code this can be seen by not supplying a command, which is the configuration of the task.  Then calling the task, which is the execution of the task, and any `doLast` closures are called.

```
$ gradle
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
hello says aConfigurationTask, via the configuration phase
:help

Welcome to Gradle 2.11.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.629 secs


$ gradle aConfigurationTask
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
hello says aConfigurationTask, via the configuration phase
:aConfigurationTask
im last to get done

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.603 secs
```

If you would like the `aConfigurationTask` task to be executed before `aExecutionTask` then you need to make `aExecutionTask` dependent on `aConfigurationTask`

```
task aExecutionTask << {
    println 'hello says aExecutionTask, via the execution phase'
}

task aConfigurationTask {
    println 'hello says aConfigurationTask, via the configuration phase'
    doLast {
        println 'im last to get done'
    }
}

aExecutionTask.dependsOn aConfigurationTask
```

When executed the `doLast` block will be called.  Here is an example:

```
$ gradle aExecutionTask
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
hello says aConfigurationTask, via the configuration phase
:aConfigurationTask
im last to get done
:aExecutionTask
hello says aExecutionTask, via the execution phase

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.597 secs
```